# Return both a form and content in a menu callback

Tags: 7, routes

I have the following code.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['mymodules/page'] = array(
    'title' => t('my module settings'),
    'description' => t('change values here'),
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    //'page arguments' => array('mymodule_page'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_page() {
  return drupal_get_form('test_form');
}

function test_form() {
  $form = array();
  $brandarray = array('nokia','siemes');

  $form['mymodule_brand'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Brand'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('mymodule_brand', 'nokia'),
    '#options' => $brandarray,
    '#description' => t('Change this.'),
  );

  $form['my_markup'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>Lorem ipsum</p>',
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

This works perfectly. What I wanted to so is returning a form and page content together, i.e after the page content, in a menu callback function; I tried using the following code:

```
function mymodule_page() {
  $variable =  drupal_get_form('test_form');
  $variable .= '<div class="newclass">here</div>';

  return $variable;
}
```

But it prints something like the following:

```
    Array
    here
```

How do I return both the form and content together in a menu callback?

Comment: In Drupal 7, the arguments for your `test_form()` are `test_form($form, &$form_state)`; you should then remove the `$form = array()` line from that form builder. See [Form generation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal 7 drupal_get_form() returns a render array instead of a string, so you should return a render array as well:

```
return array(
  'my_content' => array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'Some markup',
  ),
  'my_form' => drupal_get_form(...),
);
```

Comment: you mean to say i cannot return both form and other contents together ?? because the content after the form will be more then a markup ie. it will have a image and other content also. So is there any other way to do it?