# Is it possible to return form, themes, content in an array for my page callback function?

Tags: forms, routes, 7

For right now I need to return a themed table, a form, & content on one page. In my page callback function how do I properly store and return this variable/array?

I looked at the page below, but the code did not seem to work properly. I can only get the themed table (first in array) to show, but nothing else after it.

[Return both a form and content in a menu callback](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11672/return-both-a-form-and-content-in-a-menu-callback)

EDIT:

i tried the code below for my return, but it doesn't work. $header & $rows are both properly declared and holding the right data.

```
return array(
  'my_content' => array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'Some markup',
  ),
  'my_table' => theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)),
);
```

Comment: it seems like only the first item in my array will display then nothing else. works the same whether i'm using forms, tables, and/or just markup.

Comment: Could you post the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: ok edited the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `theme('table'..` returns HTML markup, so you are assigning a HTML string to the `my_table` key. In the example you linked `drupal_get_form` was being used which returns a renderable array, so it would have functioned correctly. Since `render()` doesn't know what to do with an HTML string, you must pass the render function the information before it has been turned into HTML:

```
return array(
  'my_content' => array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => 'Some markup',
  ),
  'my_table' => array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll fix up my code sometime today.